# Using Python, how would I return the row # along with the description in my SQLite DB?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a simple function to get all items from my sqlite database:

```
def get_items(self): 
        stmt = "SELECT description FROM items"
        return [x[0] for x in self.conn.execute(stmt)]
```

It works well but I cannot figure out how to also print the row numbers along with each row's description.  Right now it just prints description (which is a row with some text in it).  How would I get the print output to be something like this?

```
1: the text in row 1
2: the text in row 2
3: etc etc etc
```

This is needed because eventually I will need to call upon a row number to delete a row entirely. So if Python receives input to delete row 10 in the sqlite database, I would need to be able to easily identify row 10.  Kind of like if you right click + delete a row in excel and then the rest of the rows move up and become the previous number.  I would like my program to work exactly like that.

Right now I think my table is only 1 column (the description column with the text).  Do I need to add another column to identify row number?  When I do SHOW TABLE in VSCode, I actually do see a column with the numbers labeled "#", but I'm not sure if that's really a part of the table or if it's just VSCode adding that for aesthetics.

Comment: What determines which row is "first?"  Is there a column in your table which maintains this order, or is the row number just some arbitrary counter?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do not think there is a column in my table that maintains it.  I suppose I need to add this column first?  If it makes things easier to visualize, the table is loaded with chat inputs from Telegram (the Python program is a chatbot).  So there might only be 20 rows in the table at once, but I need to be able to identify each row by number so that I can delete them when I need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the 101th row, you can use `SELECT description FROM items LIMIT 1 OFFSET 101` and use `DELETE FROM items LIMIT 1 OFFSET 101` for deleting it.

Comment: The rows will be physically printed out and seen via the chat app Telegram (the program is a chatbot).  The data in the rows will be saved text from the chat group.  I would like to be able to delete rows occasionally, so instead of having to select the exact text from the row to delete that row, I'd like to be able to select the row number to delete it.  Therefore, I'd like each row to print out its row number along with it's text so the row number in the chat window is easy to identify.

Comment: You don't need to select the exact text from that row. You can give the row number at the OFFSET. `DELETE FROM items LIMIT 1 OFFSET <row_number>`. For you to print each row with row number, you can use make a for loop, which will iterate <row_number> from 0 to n an `SELECT description FROM items LIMIT 1 OFFSET <row_number>` to select the row with <row_number>.